# How could this Routes Table be improved?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this RegisterRoutes method in Global.asax, can these be abbreviated with giving the same reslut? and what about their order?

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Villages", // Route name
            "villages", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Villages", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "CreateVillage", // Route name
            "villages/create", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Villages", action = "Create", name = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Village", // Route name
            "villages/{name}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Villages", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "", // Route name
            "", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Villages", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{name}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine first with fourth route and second with third. The defualt route might also be combined with second and third. Note that you'll probably need to use some route constraints in order to make this table work properly. You can experiment with route debugger, but I would suggest you write unit tests for your routes.

**Edit:**

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{name}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Villages", action = "List", name = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
                new { action = "create|list"}
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Village", // Route name
                "villages/{name}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Villages", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Comment: By combining the second with third, do you mean to route all to the `Index` action method and first check if `name` is (create/delete) then redirect to the suitable action? and how would we combine the first and forth routes?